# Обновление контента в DIV без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, ajax

Делаю чат с помощью PHP и JS. Отправка сообщения производится через PHP, но чтобы сообщение отобразилось, необходимо перезагрузить страницу. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтоб содержимое DIV'а обновлялось без перезагрузки страницы с определённым интервалом. На просторах интернета нашёл код, но проблема в том, что у меня каким-то образом из-за этого кода в DIV'е с id messages__list появляется копия текущего сайта. Весь вопрос в том, можно ли сделать динамическое обновление контента в этом DIV'е в соответствии с текущими данными в БД? Вот, что есть сейчас:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: 'pages/general.php',
        success: function(html){
            $("#messages__list").html(html);
        }  
    });  
    return false;    

});
<div class="messages__list" id="messages__list"></div>
```

Comment: Хочу пояснить, что обновление контента в DIV'е должно быть не только после отправки формы, а на протяжении всего времени

Comment: При вызове `general.php`, к которому вы обращаетесь, должен возвращаться массив с письмами, например и перезаписываться в `#messages__list` блоке. А лучше не все письма, а последние, которых точно нет в данном блоке. А этот запрос отсылать каждые n'секунд, как в старые добрые.

Comment: И в добавление к предыдущему комментарию спешу подсказать, что для таких чатов (то есть тех, что требуют обновления "на протяжении всего времени" работы) лучше всего подойдут WebSocket'ы. Одним из преимуществ использования WebSocket'ов будет возможность не ставить таймер на каждые n-секунд для отправки запроса на сервер. Ведь в таком случае мы лишний раз перегружаем сервер. А при использовании WebSocket нам не нужно будет беспокоиться об этом. Как только сервер (скажем так) "изменится", то есть от кого-то придёт сообщение, это сообщение тут же отобразится в вашем блоке

Answer (score 0):

Язык PHP вряд-ли подойдёт, для того чтобы создать хороший чат, нужен NODE.js а именно: сокеты(socket.io), учится он легко, могу показать свой пример(это только разработки): [chat](https://chat-on-socketio.volodya-bot-developer.repl.co)

А на PHP ты можешь сделать только форум